# iOS, how do I add the signal strength bars to the iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I've managed to change the carrier name on the iphone simulator.

https://gist.github.com/0xced/3035167

However, I'm missing the network signal strength bars.
Can't find any such workarounds ?

Comment: Why you need that ? Why on simulator ?

Comment: I'd like to do a video and make it look like a proper device.

Answer (score 1):

Run the simulator, then open the terminal, then put the following

```
xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "10:00" --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100 --cellularBars 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do that in post-production.  I don't know of a way to show it using the iOS Simulator itself.

If you just need a screenshot, do it in Photoshop.  If you're making a video, add the bars as a layer over the original video in Premier or After Effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this great app http://shinydevelopment.com/status-magic/ which will help you to standardise all your status bars in screen shots with a few clicks.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't help me if I'm creating a video